# MATLAB: Capitalize first letter in string array

Tags: string, matlab

How am I supposed to access, let's say, the first character of every member of a string array? For example, I would like to capitalize the first letter of each word.

```
str = ["house", "stone", "summer"]
```

Comment: @horchler. Did  something change in recent versions of MATLAB?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Strings have been around since [2016b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html#bu5f7ms_seealso). Not to be confused with char arrays.

Comment: @horchler. Reading up on it now. thanks. I guess I've been out of touch for > 2 yrs now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using conventional slicing. To get a capital of a letter I used `upper` function

```
for i=1:size(str,2)
    str{i}(1)=upper(str{i}(1))
end
```

Comment: Are you sure about the curly braces?

Comment: Also, `size(str, 2)` -> `numel(str)`?

Comment: @Mad Physicist , you can use either `numel` or `size(str,2)`, I think there is minor or no difference. Regarding curly brackets, I use it to be able to use double subscription `str{i}(1)`. There is a difference, as curly brackets returns what is in the cell (a string), while `""` returns a cell with its content, so that I cannot extract the first character in the same line

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best solution is to use extractBefore and extractAfter:

```
upper(extractBefore(str,2)) + extractAfter(str,1);
```

Here is a performance benchmark:

```
function profFunc

    str = ["house", "stone", "summer"];  

    n = 1E5;

    % My solution
    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        str = upper(extractBefore(str,2)) + extractAfter(str,1);
    end
    toc;

    % Mikhail Genkin's solution
    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        for i=1:size(str,2)
            str{i}(1)=upper(str{i}(1));
        end
    end
    toc;

    % EdR's Solution
    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        str = string(cellfun(@(x) [upper(x(1)) x(2:end)], str, 'UniformOutput', false));
    end
    toc
end

>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 0.121556 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.034617 seconds.
Elapsed time is 10.319375 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do what you want:

```
string(cellfun(@(x) [upper(x(1)) x(2:end)], str, 'UniformOutput', false))
```

`cellfun` applies the anonymous function following it to the variable str.

The anonymous function just returns the concatenation of the upper case of the first element followed by the rest of the string.

`string` converts the cell array back to a string array.

**Edited:** to convert back to a string array as requested in the comments.

The other answer may produce easier to read code, however.

Comment: This will result in a cell array. However, I need a string array.

Comment: @Andi, you can call `string` on the cell array to make it a string array

Answer (score 0):

Adapting @matlabbit's answer to take advantage of the fact that recent versions of MATLAB can emit `string` arrays from `arrayfun`, you could write

```
capitalize = @(s) upper(extractBefore(s, 2)) + extractAfter(s, 1)
arrayfun(capitalize, ["house", "stone", "summer"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Two small somewhat pedantic comments on this post:

1. proper syntax would be:

   ```
    arrayfun(@capitalize, ["house", "stone", "summer"]);
   ```
2. Given the vectorized nature of the functions involved (upper, extractBefore, extractAfter) the arrayfun is redundant, i.e. a simple function call should work:

   ```
    capitalize(["house", "stone", "summer"]);
   ```

Note that these remarks have been tested in version R2020b although it might stand also for an earlier version. I have not tested it myself.